# HTC Radar wrong date/time after empty battery?

Tags: battery

If the **battery** is **empty** and I switch on the phone after recharge the **date and time is not correct**. Is that normal for Windows Phones or for the *HTC Radar* or is there anything wrong?

I couldn't find any information on that.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sounds like a hardware fault to me -- with a HTC Titan, I can remove the battery completely, and the real time clock is maintained.

Comment: I also thought about this. It's weird, as all other devices I use have a date/time(...) memory. It's a strange behavior..

Answer (score 2):

Some hardware problem to me.
Just like the previous answerm with my Titan I remove the battery completely and when I turn on the phone, time clock is mantained

Answer (score 2):

The mobile's main board has an internal battery (button cell). It may have rusted, disconnected or be flat. This internal battery saves the phone's date and time.